# Material-UI have different style result in production mode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, material-ui, babeljs

I am writing a React app that uses server-side rendering. I am following the [instruction](https://material-ui.com/guides/server-rendering/) here to set up a file.

Here is my `.babelrc` configuration file

```js
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": { "version": 3, "proposals": true },
        "targets": {
          "browsers": "> 1%, not ie 11, not op_mini all",
          "node": 13
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    [
      "import",
      {
        "libraryName": "@material-ui/icons",
        "libraryDirectory": "utils", // default: lib
        "camel2DashComponentName": false // default: true
      },
      "@material-ui/icons"
    ]
  ]
}
```

And this is `webpack.config.js` file

```js
const path = require("path");

const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

const commonConfig = {
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [{ test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" }]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@material-ui/core": "@material-ui/core/es"
    }
  }
};

module.exports = [
  {
    ...commonConfig,
    entry: "./src/client",
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public")
    }
  },
  {
    ...commonConfig,
    target: "node",
    entry: "./src/server",
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "server")
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals()]
  }
];
```

(Here is the full [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-dream-dffqt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) in CodeSandBox and here is in [Github](https://github.com/AnnLe4869/material-ui-crash/tree/final) if you want to try out)

The problem appear is when I bundle up the file, in development mode, everything work just fine. But when I try production mode, the CSS part starts to behave weirdly. When the file is first loaded from `localhost`, it is styled correctly (this happens in a very short time), then the style goes wrong as some styling is missing.

When I try to investigate, I find that all the style that is missing is the part I wrote with `makeStyles()`. All the built-in styles work just fine. 
I tried to remove all the `resolve` property in `webpack.config.js` following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044483/production-environment-breaks-material-ui-styling), but it doesn't work. No matter what I try to change that property, nothing happens.

So now the only way I found that can make the app work in production build is to remove the code that removes the styling file (you can find that part at the end of `client.js` file), but I'm not sure what is the result of doing so.

So my questions are:

1. What can you suggest the fix for the app?
2. Why there is such a difference between two modes, development and production? I get that the production mode will include some minification, tree shaking, etc., and the development has most of that except for minification. So why there is a difference?

   **Edit**: I found two possible and workable fixes for this bug: one is to stop removing those CSS files (code that I wrote in `client.js` file); the other one is to remove the `nodeExternal()` plugin in `webpack.config.js` and bundle everything for the server file. What do you think ?

Comment: I had this problem with material ui one or two years ago, but don't remember what I did to solve it. It was something in the hydrating. When the page loaded, it worked fine because it was static html + css. But then react needs to kick in and takes ownership of the html tree, replacing some parts in the process. This lead to some of the CSS that was minimized / optimized to change names, and my css didn't match anymore. Hope this helps you investigate.

Comment: @fmsf is your app work in development mode? I think you mean your CSS code that is written in pure CSS, not CSS-in-JS

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a similar issue, although *without* server-side rendering. It was caused by a **different order of stylesheets** in dev and prod environments, causing unwanted overwrites. In dev env all stylesheets created by `makeStyles()` were injected after ALL MUI stylesheets, but in production they were mixed.

**Solution:**

Add an option: `{ index: 1 }` to all `makeStyles()` invocations, in order to place those sheets after the MUI sheets which have an index of 0 (by default). This optional argument is passed directly to underlying JSS's `jss.createStyleSheet()` and dictates the injection order:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(
  (...),         //  styles
  { index: 1 },  //  optional argument for JSS, to set position after MUI stylesheets
)
```

(after: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62646041/624597)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue
for me it was a bad webpack optimization configuration
I took a standard config for **TerserPlugin**

Material-UI production mode is ok!

[image]

( hope this helps someone someday)